# Get most frequent value in column using Sqlite in R

Tags: sql, r, sqlite

I have 2 tables , the first one is called Athletes and has
columns that include :

athlete_id,first_name,last_name,country_id

The second table is called medals and

has the columns:

year,sport,event,athlete_id,medal

This is what a part of Athletes looks like:

```
 athlete_id first_name last_name country_id
1 BURKETOM01        Tom     Burke        USA
2 HOFMAFRI01      Fritz   Hofmann        DEU
3  LANEFRA01    Francis      Lane        USA
4 SZOKOALA01     Alajos  Szokolyi        HUN
5 BURKETOM01        Tom     Burke        USA
6 JAMISHER01    Herbert   Jamison        USA
```

This is what a part of Medals looks like:

```
year         sport    event athlete_id  medal

1 1896 Track & Field 100m Men BURKETOM01   GOLD
2 1896 Track & Field 100m Men HOFMAFRI01 SILVER
3 1896 Track & Field 100m Men  LANEFRA01 BRONZE
4 1896 Track & Field 100m Men SZOKOALA01 BRONZE
5 1896 Track & Field 400m Men BURKETOM01   GOLD
6 1896 Track & Field 400m Men JAMISHER01 SILVER
```

I need to find the athlete with the highest number of medals and the number of medals he has won.
The correct answer is

```
 full_name top_no_medals
1 Larisa Latynina 18
```

I saw a few posts similar to this and tried using what was suggested there
This is my code:

```
dbGetQuery(olympics.db,statement = 
             'SELECT Athletes.first_name ||" "|| Athletes.last_name AS full_name,COUNT(Medals.athlete_id) 
           AS top_no_medals
           FROM Athletes
           JOIN  Medals ON Medals.athlete_id=Athletes.athlete_id
           GROUP BY full_name
           ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
           LIMIT 1'
)
```

what I am trying to do is combine the 2 tables according to the variable athlete_id and the count this variable.
For some reason the answer I get is with too many medals.

```
          full_name top_no_medals
1   Larisa Latynina           324
```

It seems there is a mistake couting the medal.
Now I am sure the data is correct, when I check Medals table to see
What is the most common athlete_id I get the correct one.
This is the code and answer:

```
dbGetQuery(olympics.db,statement = ' Select athlete_id, count(*) AS top_no_medals
 From Medals
Group By athlete_id
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
LIMIT 1')

 athlete_id top_no_medals
1 LATYNLAR01            18
```

This athlete_id is the one associated with Larisa Latynina so its not a problem
in the medals table.

Comment: **Please do not delete your question** once people have taken the trouble to answer it.  Can you comment on why you want it deleted?

Answer (score 2):

Based on the fact that your second query works, the problem would appear to be the column `athletes(athlete_id)`.  This seems to be duplicated.

Try running this query:

```
select athlete_id, count(*) as cnt
from athletes
group by athlete_id
order by count(*) desc;
```

The maximum `cnt` should be 1.  If not, you have a problem with your data.

Oh, never mind with that.  Your `Atheletes` table *does* have duplicates.  Assuming the name is always the same, you can do:

```
SELECT a.full_name, COUNT(*) AS top_no_medals
FROM (SELECT a.athlete_id,
             MAX(a.first_name || ' ' || a.last_name) as full_name
      FROM Athletes a 
      GROUP BY athlete_id
     ) a
     Medals m
     ON m.athlete_id = a.athlete_id
GROUP BY full_name
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

You could also revise your query to use `COUNT(DISTINCT)`, assuming that each medal has a unique identifier:

```
SELECT a.first_name || ' ' || a.last_name AS full_name,
       COUNT(DISTINCT m.medal_id) as top_no_medals
FROM Athletes a JOIN
     Medals m
     ON m.athlete_id = a.athlete_id
GROUP BY full_name
ORDER BY COUNT(DISTINCT m.medal_id) DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: Note that 324 is 18*18 so I would guess that Larisa Latynina is repeated 18 times in Atheletes table. Could the Atheletes table be the medaled atheletes?

Comment: @aichao . . . If I had to speculate, the `Athletes` table is everyone who competed.  My guess is that Larisa won a medal in every competition she was in.

Answer (score 0):

Given that the second query (get medal count) works, I would suggest computing it first then joining with Athletes to get name matching that ID:

```
SELECT a.first_name || ' ' || a.last_name AS full_name, top_no_medals
FROM (SELECT athlete_id, count(*) AS top_no_medals
      FROM Medals
      GROUP BY athlete_id
      ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
      LIMIT 1) m
JOIN Athletes a ON m.athlete_id = a.athlete_id
```